# indefinite integral question!

Tags: calculus

I tried using integration by parts, $\int u\,{\rm d}v= uv- \int v\,{\rm d}u$, on the following integral: 
$$\int x\arcsin(8x)\,{\rm d}x$$ 
This is what I have so far, I don't know what to do after.
$$u= x$$
$$dv= \arcsin(8x)dx$$

$$\frac{x^2}{2}\arcsin(8x)- \int \frac{4x^2}{\sqrt{1-64x^2}}dx$$

Comment: Show your work and maybe we can see where your mistake or misunderstanding is?

Comment: I think that integration by parts should work fine here. We can see that the $x$ will vanish after one iteration.

Comment: The standard mathematical functions can be typeset by adding a `\ ` before the name, e.g. `\arcsin(x)` gives $\arcsin(x)$. To get the correct behavior for the square root function use brackets: `\sqrt{1-x}` gives  $\sqrt{1-x}$. See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more details.

Comment: You have selected the wrong u and dv, if you switch them life will be easier

Comment: Switching the u and dv complicates the problem even more. I don't think that is the way to go about doing this.

Comment: Look here in Wikipedia article on IBP and find the "rule of thumb" called LIATE its a geat way to start IBP problems. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Comment: you can try substitution $u=8x$ or integration by parts

Comment: i did use the liate rule of thumb idea and made the inverse trig= u

Comment: @user277852 I posted an alternative way to make integration by parts little easier...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a trig substitution on your last integral:

$$\int \frac{4x^2}{\sqrt{1-64x^2}}\, dx = \int \frac{4x^2}{\sqrt{1-16(4x^2)}}\, dx$$

$$\text{let $a=2x$}$$

$$\int \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{1-16a^2}}\, da$$

I think this is equal to an inverse trig function plus some constants (correct me if I'm wrong) so you'll get a pretty simple answer to the integral that you'll have to add to the other half of your integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

$u=8x  \ du=8dx \rightarrow x=\frac{u}{8}$

$=\int \frac{u}{8} arcsin (u) \frac{1}{8} du$

$=\frac{1}{8} \int \frac{u}{8} arcsin (u) du$

$=\frac{1}{8} \frac{1}{8} \int u arcsin (u) du$

Now apply integration by parts and you should get your answer

Comment: I was able to use this method but got stuck when I tried to integrate x^2/2sqrt(1-x^2)

Comment: $\int uv^{'} =uv -\int u^{'} v$

$u=arcsin(u), u^{'} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}, v^{'} =u, v=\frac{u^2}{2}$

Comment: I got up to this point. I am stuck on integrating vdu

Comment: i assume you talk about:

$\int \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} du$

You can do another substitution:

$\sqrt{a-bx^2} \ substitute \ x=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} \sin (u)$

in your case a=1 b=1, it will get complex but you will be able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

While integration by parts certainly works, it leads to a lot of complicated algebra. You can, if you wish to see an alternative way, avoid "complicated" integration by parts, here is how:

First u-sub $8x=t$ with $dx=\frac{1}{8}dt$ Integral becomes $\frac{1}{64}\int tarcsint\,{\rm d}t $ Now another u-sub: $arcsint=v$ with $dt=cosvdv$ With $t=sinv$ the integral now becomes:  $\frac{1}{64}\int vsinvcosv\,{\rm d}t $ Now using the double angle formula for sine we arrive at: $\frac{1}{128}\int vsin2v\,{\rm d}t $ Doing integration by parts here is lots simpler since the anti derivative of sine is just a cosine. You just need to back sub which is not too hard